# Performing a command multiple times in different folders

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

So currently I have a bunch of text files stored in separate folders located in a single folder which I would like to merge together using command prompt. I would like to merge each set of text files into one and have the output file placed in the same folder.

For example, in a folder I have:

text1.txt, 
text2.txt, 
text3.txt

and would like to merge all txt documents to an output text document and have it saved under one file within the same folder.

I need to perform this on a large number of folders.
Is there a way I can perform a for loop in a for loop? Perhaps there's another way to do this? Please help.

Comment: "Is there a way I can perform a for loop in a for loop?" Yes, why don't you just try it.

Comment: It's helpful to provide more detail (OS, what application you want to use, etc.) and evidence of what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

One loop should do.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      pushd "%%a"
          if exist *.txt copy *.txt output >nul
          if exist output ren output output.txt
      popd
)
```